# Find the perimeter of the trapezoid from the 3 side lengths.

Tags: geometry

> What we know about the trapezoid ABCD (AB and CD are respectively its large and small bases) is that AB=9 cm,AC=6 cm,AD=8 cm,CD=4 cm.  Determine the perimeter of the trapezoid.

It is quite tricky.

I tried using the Pythagorean theorem, but ended with:

$(9 -x)^2 + y^2 = 36$, which led nowhere.

I am confused as to what I can do now.

Comment: @mathlove, thanks for answering here again! These questions I've been posting are not exactly top written questions. Which part is strange though? The answer is stated to be: 33

Comment: can you post a picture please?

Comment: @mathlove, oh sorry! I was writing a different question first! AH. Sorry

Comment: @mathlove, edited. How can I approach this ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, there is no picture along with this.

Comment: you will need the theorem of cosines

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, no angles are here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = BC$ and let $\theta = \angle BAC = \angle ACD$. Then by applying Cosine Law to each triangle, we have:
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 6^2 + 9^2 - 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 9 \cdot \cos \theta \\
8^2 &= 6^2 + 4^2 - 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot \cos \theta
\end{align*}
Divide the first equation by $9$, divide the second equation by $4$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{9} &= 4 + 9 - 2 \cdot 6 \cdot \cos \theta \\
16 &= 9 + 4 - 2 \cdot 6 \cdot \cos \theta
\end{align*}
Subtract the two equations:
$$
\frac{x^2}{9} - 16 = 0
\iff x^2 = 9 \cdot 16
\iff x = 3 \cdot 4
$$